# IE8 incompatibility of z-index and body:after

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, incompatibility

I have a two-way gradient background and a navigation bar. All the browsers display right except IE8 (even IE7 is ok).

The simplified code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/HKg9d/3/

If you adjust the window size and let the square cross the two parts of the background, the bottom part will overlap the square, only in IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `position:relative` to the `.nav`. `z-index` Applies to *positioned elements* (from the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index))